# Passing scriptblock as an argument to Invoke-Command scriptblock in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a powershell script in which I have been trying to pass scriptblock(i.e $sb) as an argument to  another scriptblock. However, I keep getting error that:

> Cannot convert the "{get-member}" value of type "System.String" to
> type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock

**a.psm1:**

```
$sb = {get-member}
# $type = $sb.GetType().FullName => Returns scriptblock as data type
$result = Invoke-Command -Session "DC" -Scriptblock
{
    Param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [scriptblock]
         $sb
     )
 //Do some task
} -ArgumentList $sb
```

**I am not able to figure out why $sb is treated as a string instead of Scriptblock?**

The only way it works is changing the argument inside the **Invoke-Command** scriptblock to be of type string instead of Scriptblock.
I am not sure why scriptblocks gets implicitly converted to string while passing argument to **Invoke-Command** scriptblock.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue; can you put the full code here?

Answer (score 2):

When a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (type `[scriptblock]`, `{ ... }` as a literal) is passed to **code that executes *out-of-process***, such as during **remoting** (your case) or in **background jobs**, XML-based serialization and deserialization must be performed.

On deserialization in the target process, **`[scriptblock]` instances indeed unexpectedly become *strings***.

Unfortunately and bewilderingly, **this behavior has been declared *by design*(!)** - see [GitHub issue #11698](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11698).

Your only option is to **pass the script block('s source code) *as a string***, and **convert it back** to a script block via **`[scriptblock]::Create()`**; a simple example, using a background job:

```bash
Start-Job { 

  param([string] $scriptBlockSourceCode) # Note the type: [string]

  # Use [scriptblock]::Create() to turn the string into a script block,
  # and execute it with &
  & ([scriptblock]::Create($scriptBlockSourceCode))

} -ArgumentList { 'hi' } |
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove
```